# In Intellij, how do I toggle between camel case and underscore spaced?

Tags: java, coding-style, intellij-idea

At my company we have two different style guides for java vs sql.  In java I have a field named `historyOfPresentIllness` and when i write the sql, I want to name it `history_of_present_illness`.  Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch from one to the other when I have the phrase highlighted?  Or perhaps a plugin that can do this?

While I'm asking, I may as well ask if there's a way to turn `historyOfPresentIllness` to `history-of-present-illness`.  That's from java to clojure style.

Answer (score 347, accepted):

Two plugins offer this feature:

I use a plugin called [String Manipulation](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=2162) which does what you need (and more).

Select `historyOfPresentIllness` and press <kbd>Alt / option</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to bring up the plugin menu, then press:

- <kbd>5</kbd> - **To snake_case (or to camelCase)** which converts to `history_of_present_illness`
- <kbd>6</kbd>  -  **To hyphen-case (or to snake_case)** which converts to `history-of-present-illness`

To make this easier, you could set up a shortcut at `File | Settings | Keymap`.

---

There also is the [CamelCase](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7160-camelcase) plugin.

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Alt / option</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> toggles the selection between formats:

`historyOfPresentIllness` --> `history_of_present_illness` --> `HISTORY_OF_PRESENT_ILLNESS` --> `HistoryOfPresentIllness` --> `historyOfPresentIllness`

You can also undo your changes (now that a bug in the plugin got fixed).

Comment: @tieTYT Yeah, it's pretty annoying because you get a pop-up message telling you that the file has changes that cannot be undone...if not for that, it would have been the more convenient choice.

Comment: @tieTYT Just occurred to me that to simplify the first approach, you could record a macro `Edit > Macros > Start recording macro` and then add a simple key-mapping for your macro `Settings > Keymap > Macros > YourMacro (right-click > Add Keyboard Shortcut)`

Comment: String Manipulation now also contains actions to toggle between all kinds of cases...You can setup a shortcut to any action (there are too many of them to have some default).

Comment: @DannyMo - For me, it's `5` for `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` and `J` is for `Trim all spaces`. Using Mac OS X 10.10.5, PhpStorm 10.0.1, String Manipulation 4.1.135.445.1.

Comment: I can confirm that the CamelCase plugin works fine with IntelliJ 2016.2.3

Comment: Both plugins only renames selected variables but aren't searching for all usages of these variables. Is it only me or you have the same behavior? Is it possible to rename a variable with all of its usages?

Comment: Oh, nevermind! Just click (or make a macro): SHIFT + F6 (refactor), then change case with one of the plugins and then hit ENTER.

Answer (score 101):

Very simple press `Clr + F` to open **Find/Replace** panel and check **[✓] Regex** copy past regex

**Find:** `[_]{1,1}([a-z])`

**Replace:** `\U$1`

Press [Replace all] button, Enjoy

---

Thanks @piotrek for `_some_awe_var` to `_someAweVar`

Use Find: `(\w)[_]{1,1}([a-z])` 
Replace: `$1\U$2`

Comment: Just for completeness sake, from camelCase to snake_case: find `([A-Z]{1,1})` and replace by `_\l$1`, with both *Regex* and *Match case* optiones toggled.

Comment: This is great but in TypeScript, often private members begin with an `_` and this will make them begin capitalized.

Comment: @StackUnderflow use *Find:* `(\w)[_]{1,1}([a-z])` *Replace:* `$1\U$2`

Comment: I suppose that "very simple" is sarcasm, isn't it? I chose rather the *String Manipulation* plugin from the accepted answer :)

Comment: I think (\w)_([a-z]) would be simpler? No need for [ ] and { } just for one symbol.

Answer (score 25):

### From snake_case to CamelCase

- Find: `(\w)[_]{1,1}([a-z])`
- Replace: `$1\U$2`
- Settings:

  - Match Case
  - Regex

### From CamelCase to snake_case:

- Find: `([A-Z])`
- Replace: `\_\L$1`
- Settings:

  - Match Case
  - Regex

Comment: For your CamelCase to snake_case, you better make sure you have something selected.  As written it will replace every single capital letter in your project to a lowercase proceeded by an underscore.  That seems bad to me.  At very least you need to limit it to something like `(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])` to get only capitals that follow a lowercase.

Comment: Thanks! Just copied a lot of snake_case fields from database schema and using this it really saved me a bit of time. Especially great that you can just navigate through every match manually

Comment: How would one adapt the camelCase to snake_case solution so that it could be used within an XML context? For example: from `<addPrimaryKey columnNames="somethingLikeThis"/>` to `<addPrimaryKey columnNames="something_like_this"/>`.

Answer (score 7):

If you are OK with PyCharm also refactoring usages, launch the "Rename" tool (Refactor > Rename). The window pops up with drop down list and you should see the snake_case version of the text in the list (you can open the window and switch to the snake_case with key-strokes so it can be pretty fast).

Answer (score 5):

Answer above is almost perfect, but note that it will change variables like `_something` or `this._something` into `Something` and `this.Something`. I didn't want that in my case, as leading _ was used to denote "private" variables (old JS project). I slightly modified this approach:

**Find:** (\w)[_]{1,1}([a-z])

**Replace:** $1\U$2

This will ensure that only variables with `_` is in the middle will be affected.

Comment: "above" is meaningless because answers can be sorted - your "above" is not everyone's "above" so please avoid using "above" or "below" to describe content on this site, instead give the author's name, thanks

Comment: The "above" answer referenced is [@Qamar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46645833/3291390)