# change all name variables and functions from upper to lower Camelcase in android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have an Andriod project.

this project has many classes and variables.

all functions and variables in this project name's start with upper case.

I need to change to lower case.

```
Class A {
   String Boo;
   void HandlerMyJob(){
   }
}
```

to

```
Class A {
   String boo;
   void handlerMyJob(){
   }
}
```

can I use Android Studio for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350359/in-intellij-how-do-i-toggle-between-camel-case-and-underscore-spaced

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I need to change all variables and function at once time. not use one by one

Comment: @RasoulMiri Guessing by the question these variables and functions have different names too ?

Comment: yes, all variables and functions in classes and project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the **Structural Search and Replace (SSR)** functionality. Please make sure to update IntelliJ IDEA to the latest version to benefit from latest updates to SSR.

Details on the functionality and a few usage examples [can be found here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html).

In your case, you can use the following template to fix variable names:

```
<replaceConfiguration name="InitFinder" text="$FieldType$ $Field$;" recursive="false" caseInsensitive="true" type="JAVA" pattern_context="default" reformatAccordingToStyle="false" shortenFQN="true" replacement="$FieldType$ $Field2$;">
  <constraint name="__context__" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Field" regexp="\b^[A-Z]\w*\b" maxCount="2147483647" target="true" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="FieldType" within="" contains="" />
  <variableDefinition name="Field2" script="&quot;Field.name.uncapitalize()&quot;" />
</replaceConfiguration>
```

You can alter it in the Structural Replace window in order to cover deviant cases.

---

Renaming methods using SSR can be tricky - but is still doable.

```
void MyMethod2(String field2) {
        mField2 = field2;
    }
```

For any method having the same structure as one above, the 'uncapitalizing' search/replace template will be:

```
<replaceConfiguration name="constructors &amp; methods" text="class $Class$ {&#10;    void $Method$($ParameterType$ $Parameter$){&#10;        $Statement$;&#10;    };&#10;}" recursive="false" caseInsensitive="true" type="JAVA" pattern_context="member" reformatAccordingToStyle="true" shortenFQN="true" replacement="void $Method2$($ParameterType$ $Parameter$){&#10;    $Statement$;&#10;}&#10;">
  <constraint name="__context__" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Method" regexp="\b^[A-Z][a-z]\w*\b" target="true" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="ParameterType" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Parameter" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Class" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Statement" within="" contains="" />
  <variableDefinition name="Method2" script="&quot;Method.name.uncapitalize()&quot;" />
</replaceConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Refractor to rename all variable or class or methods names.

In Windows :

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

In Mac :

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

Choose rename all occurrences.

[image]

Comment: I need to change all variables and function at once time. not use one by one

Comment: There is two option you will get check the answer

Comment: this trick for one variable in all around project, I need to change all variables in the project.

Answer (score 1):

you just right click on class or variable name and refactor it that's it