# How to perform custom operations on strings in idea

Tags: python, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have some strings like `receipt_success_bill_count`, I want to convert it to `receiptSuccessBillCount`.

I want to write a python script, and bind it to a shortcut. Just like `⇧ ⌘ U` can Toggle Case,

background: lots of columns to properties

```xml
<result column="receipt_total_count" jdbcType="BIGINT" property="receiptTotalCount" />
<result column="receipt_success_count" jdbcType="BIGINT" property="receiptSuccessCount" />
<result column="receipt_success_bill_count" jdbcType="BIGINT" property="receiptSuccessBillCount" />
<result column="bill_success_count" jdbcType="BIGINT" property="billSuccessCount" />
<result column="bill_success_bill_count" jdbcType="BIGINT" property="billSuccessBillCount" />
<result column="message_effective_ds" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="message_effective_ds" />
```

Comment: If you want to write a python script why did you tag this with the "java" tag?

Comment: See "in idea" in the title, I am writing Java code in IntelliJ IDEA. I want to write a python script and bind it into a shortcut in IDEA.

Comment: Then the question has nothing to do with java. Got it.

Comment: You can try to add your script as [External Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-external-tools.html) and assign a custom shortcut for it under `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`

Comment: Just in case, there's a [solution already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350359/in-intellij-how-do-i-toggle-between-camel-case-and-underscore-spaced) to change case.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I use External Tool. My python script print output in Run Panel. Is there any way to print output right on the editor panel?